# Volume estimation with differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem reads:

"Using differential equations, estimate the volume necessary to build a tube that is 12m long and has an inner diameter of 25cm and an outer diameter of 25,2 cm."

Unfortunately I couldn't find any similar problems online so I'm at a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a cylinder is given by:$$
V = \pi r^2h
$$Since the inner and outer diameter can be seen as a change in radius, we could differentiate with respect to the radius to get:$$
dV = 2\pi rh~dr
$$We only want the outer shell of our growing cylinder, since it will have the shape of a tube. The volume of this outer shell is given by $\Delta V$:$$
\Delta V \approx 2\pi rh~\Delta r
$$We can use $r=25/2$, $h=12$ and $\Delta r = (25-25.2)/2$.

Just make sure you convert units to be consistent.

Comment: I should always differentiate over the variables that change, correct?

Comment: Correct. If you have a variable that changes, then you can use its $\Delta$ for the differential.

Answer (score 0):

you can approximate the volume by the formula $ volume \simeq surface \space area \times height. $ approximate volume is $$\text{volume} \simeq 1200 \times (\pi 25) \times 0.1 \text{cm}^3. $$